# Commenting JavaScript functions á la Python Docstrings

Tags: javascript, python, comments, docstring

It is valid JavaScript to write something like this:

```
function example(x) {
    "Here is a short doc what I do.";
    // code of the function
}
```

The string actually does nothing. Is there any reason, why one shouldn't comment his/her functions in JavaScript in this way?

Two points I could think of during wiriting the question:

- The string literal must be initiated, which could be costly in the long run
- The string literal will not be recognized as removable by JS minifiers

Any other points?

**Edit:** Why I brought up this topic: I found something like this on [John Resig's Blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/), where the new ECMA 5 standard uses a not assigned string literal to enable "strict mode". Now it was my interest to just evaluate, if there could be uses or dangers in doing such documentation.

Comment: And the interest of doing this is... ?

Comment: You're not writing Python, so don't pretend like you are.

Comment: Actually, YUI Compressor recognizes it as removable and removes it.

Comment: @mjv: ...to experiment and evaluate features of a language. Have you never played Lego (TM)?

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to see, if there are any points in doing this.

Comment: If you want this string to be available in runtime, you can make the function return it in response to some special argument

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's really no point in doing this in Javascript.  In Python, the string is made available as the `__doc__` member of the function, class, or module.  So these docstrings are available for introspection, etc.

If you create strings like this in Javascript, you get no benefit over using a comment, plus you get some disadvantages, like the string always being present.

Comment: Some JavaScript engines optimize this and remove the string. `(function(){"foobar"}).toString(-1) === "function () {}"` in Spidermonkey.

Comment: That's cool, but there's still nothing to be gained by doing this in Javascript.  Why subvert the design of the language?

Comment: I'm not fully sure, if it is subversion: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Comment: You can modify the technique so that you do get the benefits of introspection and being able to see the strings in an interactive javascript shell:

    `foo = function(bar) { return bar * bar };
    foo.__doc__ = 'foo(bar): returns bar squared';`

Then in a shell, you get something like this:


`> foo
{ [Function] __doc__: 'foo(bar): returns bar squared' }`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to add multi-line strings to my code without littering it with \n's. It looks like this module fits the bill:
[https://github.com/monolithed/**doc**](https://github.com/monolithed/__doc__)

Unfortunately, the comments won't survive minification, but I suppose you could write a compile task to convert docstrings to "\n" format.

Comment: That's very interesting, but, please be patient with me, I don't see the relevance to the question. Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way!

Comment: It is a JS equivalent to a Python docstring.  So you add your doc as a comment, and then can access it via the __doc__ property.  You can see some examples in the tests here: 
https://github.com/monolithed/__doc__/blob/master/tests/__doc__.js

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but you could use this approach for documentation.

Comment: Ah, I see: I have the advantages of Python's `__doc__` in standard JS comments, so no need for the experiments with strings... Good idea. (My original intention with the question was to evaluate the very possibility of using strings w/o assigning them, but I agree, it's pointless without use case.)

Comment: By the way, I'm not a huge fan of how `__doc__.js` modifies the object prototype.  But you can easily just extract a comment from a function with regex, like I did in the extractFirstComment function here: https://github.com/adampasz/docopt-js-shim/blob/master/index.js

Comment: For anyone reading this today, [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) were introduced in ES2015 and facilitate multi-line strings without the explicit use of `\n` characters.